# Redirect and requests in flask microframework

Tags: python, http, redirect, response, flask

Is there any difference in the way redirects and requests are handled in the flask micro-framework? I have a bunch of functions which are to be run before a request is made but apparently they are not being run whenever there is a redirect to another url.

Comment: Did you mean redirects and responses?

Answer (score 1):

If you `return redirect('someurl')` in your view function it will result in a `Location` header being sent to the client. So unless the client decides to load the target from cache instead the view function of the target URL will be executed just like if the client accessed it directly.